# Merging of two lists - how to get all integers?

Tags: java

I am merging two lists. Works well, however, it doesn't merge all integers in each list, i.e. if I have three "1" in list a, and two "1" in list b, then the new list will only contain three "1". I want the new list to contain five "1", but how should I write then? Sorry for the explanation, I hope you understand what I mean.

```
 public SortedList merge(SortedList l) {
     return new SortedList(merge(first, l.first));
   }

   private static Node merge(Node a, Node n) {
     if (a==null && n==null)
   return null;
  else if (a==null)
   return copy(n);
  else if (n==null)
   return copy(a);
  else if (a.data<n.data)
   return new Node(a.data, merge(a.next, n));
  else if (n.data<a.data)
   return new Node(n.data, merge(a, n.next));
  else
   return new Node(a.data, merge(a.next, n.next));
 }
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what your code does, but this `(a.data<n.data)` should maybe be changed to `(a.data<=n.data)`. The same with `(n.data<a.data)`?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Thank you so much!